# Error importing dependency in Cypress Cucumber

Tags: javascript, npm, cucumber, cypress

I have a problem when importing some dependencies in Cucumber. The error is the following:

```
Running: features\my_feature.feature...                                          (1 of 1)
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update`

Oops...we found an error preparing this test file:

  cypress\integration\features\my_feature.feature

The error was:

Error: Cannot find module 'C:gitdevelopPROJECT
ode_modulescypress-cucumber-preprocessorlib/resolveStepDefinition' from 'C:\git\develop\PROJECT\cypress\integration\features'


This occurred while Cypress was compiling and bundling your test code. This is usually caused by:

- A missing file or dependency
- A syntax error in the file or one of its dependencies

Fix the error in your code and re-run your tests.
```

I'm not able to run the features I worked on because of this. I suppose the key for the error is in line 3. I'll explain this, the path of the file is the following: `C:\git\develop\PROJECT\cypress\node_modules\cypress-cucumber-preprocessor\lib\resolveStepDefinition`, but the library is recognizing the `\n` substring from `\node_modules` as a break line and is not recognizing the \ in the path. I don't know if that makes any sense.

I don't know what to publish here, because I don't think it's related to a configuration or anything like that. If you have any idea or need anything else, please, tell me. I'll publish all that could be required.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your file structure is like:

cypress/integration/myfeatures/feature1.feature

cypress/integration/myfeatures/feature1/feature1.js

This structure is required by cypress-cucumber-preprocessor and might be why you get the resolveStepDefinition error message. See the [github docs](https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor#step-definitions)

I believe the error message you get is misleading you in thinking the '\n' is an issue in the code, but in reality, it's the console that can't properly handle the '\n'.